# Как вывести определенные узлы XML?

Tags: c#, xml

Нужно вывести дочерние узлы определенного узла. Вот xml документ:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<head>
  <Klassi>
    <klass>
      Класс 1
      <klass Attr="Класс 15">Класс 15</klass>
      <klass Attr="Класс 15">Класс 15</klass>
    </klass>
    <klass>Класс 2</klass>
    <klass>Класс 3</klass>
    <klass>Класс 4</klass>
    <klass>Класс 5</klass>
    <klass>
      Класс 15
      <gruppa>А</gruppa>
      <gruppa>Б</gruppa>
      <gruppa>В</gruppa>
    </klass>
    <klass>
      Класс 9
      <gruppa>А</gruppa>
    </klass>
    <klass Attr="Класс 777">
      Класс 777
      <gruppa>А</gruppa>
      <gruppa>Б</gruppa>
      <gruppa>В</gruppa>
    </klass>
  </Klassi>
</head>
```

Мне нужно вывести дочерние узлы, ну например, элемента 'Класс 15'. Т.е. в данном случае я хочу получить список вот таких значений: А Б В. Так вот как это сделать?

Comment: Ваш XML невалидный, дефисы там точно должны присутствовать?

Comment: Да, он рабочий. Проблема лишь в том, что невозможно корректно справиться с поставленной задачей. Кодов нет рабочих.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ну можно пройтись по дереву и выбрать те элементы `klass`, которые содержат текст `"Класс 15"`. Давайте воспользуется Linq2Xml:

```
var doc = XDocument.Load("file.xml");  // Загружаем документ
var klass15 = doc.Element("head")    // Берем элемент head
                 .Element("Klassi")  // В нем элемент Klassi
                 .Elements("klass")  // В нем все элементы klass
// Из них выбираем те, которые содержат текст и этот текст содержит строку "Класс 15"
                 .Where(e => e.Nodes()
                              .OfType<XText>()
                              .Where(t => t.Value.Contains("Класс 15")).Any());
foreach (var e in klass15.Elements("gruppa"))  // Пройдемся по его элементам gruppa
    Console.WriteLine(e.Value);  // И выведем их содержимое
```

Вывод:

```
А
Б
В
```

Comment: Огромное спасибо, что откликнулись! За все время, что я уже пересмотрел и перепробовал кодов этот самый лучший и понятный по логике. Но тем не менее у меня он не работает. Я чувствую, что уже что-то близкое, но пока вывода нет. У меня Visual Studio 2013. Может быть из-за этого проблемы какие-то? Баги?

Comment: @AlexFox, как именно не работает?

Comment: var doc = XDocument.Load("Gruppi.xml");  // Загружаем документ
                      var klass15 = doc.Element("head")    // Берем элемент head
                      .Element("Klassi")  
                      .Elements("klass")  
                 .Where(t => t.Nodes()
                              .OfType<XText>()
                              .Where(s => s.Value.Contains("Класс 777")).Any());
foreach (var p in klass15.Elements("gruppa"))
{
    listBox1.Items.Add(p.LastNode);
} Вывода нет в listBox1. Он пустой остается

Comment: А почему `p.LastNode`?

Comment: Прошу прощение все же listBox1.Items.Add(p.Value); Это я по привычке пытаюсь найти решение проблемы))

Comment: @AlexFox, у меня ваш код работает нормально

Comment: А можете прислать проект? Alex512kar@inbox.ru

Comment: Вообще поиск по тексту довольно ненадежен, у вас в строке `"Класс 777"` может быть лишний пробел или другой регистр или символ в другой раскладке и тогда нужный элемент не будет найден, убедитесь, что ваш xml совпадает с тем, что приведен в вопросе

Comment: Да, все правильно. Несовпадения исключены. А какой студией вы пользуетесь?

Comment: @AlexFox, проект: http://rgho.st/6SF44hTG6 студия 2017 у меня

Comment: Проект не открывается. Возможно, у меня Studia 2013 не способна такие коды выполнять. Попытаюсь поставить 2017. Просто, я ставил уже 2017 и с нее не открывался ни один проект.

Comment: Да, у вас код работает прекрасно, но у меня в проекте в listBox1 ничего не добавляется. В консоль тоже при соответствующей команде не выводится. Не знаю, что и делать....

Comment: Хочу Вас поблагодарить! Теперь все работает! Огромнейшее спасибо Вы очень помогли. Ошибка была у меня, обращался к старому xml файлу, поэтому и не выводило)) Еще раз спасибо!

Comment: Рад помочь, пометьте ответ галочкой, чтобы топик не висел открытым