# C# xml Как считать определенные элементы?

Tags: c#, xml

Имеется xml файл вида:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
-<head>-
<Klassi>
<klass1>Класс 1</klass1>
<klass2>Класс 2</klass2>
<klass3>Класс 3</klass3>
<klass4>Класс 4</klass4>
-<klass5>Класс 5<gruppa>5-Б</gruppa></klass5>
<klass6>Класс 6</klass6>
-<klass7>Класс 7<gruppa>7-В</gruppa></klass7>
<klass8>Класс 8</klass8
><klass9>Класс 9</klass9>
<klass10>Класс 10</klass10>
<klass11>Класс 11</klass11>
</Klassi>
</head>
```

Как считать группы (gruppa) у элемента, например, klass7? НО это еще не все: У меня есть имеется только значение элемента klass7, а именно "Класс 7" - Необходимо по этому элементу определить соответствующий узел т.е. klass7 и вывести его дочерние элементы.

P.s. Прошу прощения за плохо читаемый xml файл. Не понимаю как его корректно выводить здесь на сайте)

Comment: Вам уже дважды давали ответы на почти аналогичные вопросы.

Comment: Все верно, они очень похожи, но при этом у меня не получатся вывести валидный результат именно под эту конкретную задачу, тем более здесь появилось противное дополнительное условие)

Comment: Что за черточки у вас в документе: `-<head>-` - этот документ невалидный, они точно там присутствуют? Или это вы так неудачно скопировали откуда-то?

Comment: И да, вопрос пока абсолютно ни чем не отличается от этого: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/765625/218063

Comment: Да, это оно так копируется. Вопрос очень очень похож, но отличие в том, что в том вопросе узлы называются klass, а в данном случае klass1, klass2, klass3... И это мне доставило проблему. Тот код уже не работает. Т.к. я новичок в C# xml мне не удается подстроится под новую задачу, имея аналогичное решение)

Comment: И вот проблема еще: У меня есть только значение узла, например, "Класс 7", а по нему уже нужно найти сам элемент klass7 и его дочерние элементы

Comment: Попробуйте код из того ответа, но вместо `.Elements("klass")` напишите `.Elements()` - он вернет ВСЕ дочерние элементы

Comment: Чтобы пользователь получил уведомление о комментарии, пожалуйста, используйте обращение через @ИмяПользователя. Иначе приходится заходить в тему самостоятельно.

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Как вывести определенные узлы XML?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/765625/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%b2%d1%8b%d0%b2%d0%b5%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b8-%d0%be%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b4%d0%b5%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%b5-%d1%83%d0%b7%d0%bb%d1%8b-xml)

Comment: @АндрейNOP. Я попробовал сделать по Вашему совету и получилось, единственное, там проблема в том, что вывод выглядит так: <gruppa>5-A</gruppa><gruppa>5-B</gruppa>. Как это можно исправить?

Comment: Не может быть, я в цикле вывожу только значения: `foreach (var e in klass15.Elements("gruppa"))  // Пройдемся по его элементам gruppa
    Console.WriteLine(e.Value);  // И выведем их содержимое`

Comment: Покажите код, выложите на https://pastebin.com/ например

Comment: @АндрейNOP. https://pastebin.com/VW8dTBtJ

Comment: `listBox1.Items.Add(t);` - пропустили `.Value`

Comment: @АндрейNOP. Большое спасибо! А то ночами сижу проект доделываю уже не вижу элементарного)))

Comment: В следующий раз выкладывайте код попытки в самом вопросе и объясняйте что именно не получилось.